# However to convert string value to raw string as download path for selenium chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Anyone know how to transfer string variable to raw string? I try to write small program to click download button to download from web by using selenium drive. I need to use variable for **"download.default_directory"** value

if i set download.default_directory value as **'/User/xxxx'** I am able to see correct download path on chrome driver and I can see the download file from path. However
if I change value to

```
path = '/User/xxxx'
"download.default_directory": repr(path)
```

download path in chrome become **'/User/xxxx'** the incorrect path

```
from pago.driver import WebDriver
import os
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
path = '/User/ycc/'
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": '/User/xxx',
    #"download.default_directory": repr('/User/xxx'),   -> failed
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = WebDriver(desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'chrome'}, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.docker.com/get-started')
locator = '//a[.="Download for Mac"]'
time.sleep(3)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
button.click()
```

Comment: Why are you using `repr(path)`? What is the point? If you want *raw string* use `path = r'/User/xxxx'`

Comment: i need to use path as variable. so I cannot write something like r'path'